# How to add double quote in csv file where field contains space?

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, sed

One feature of legacy code doesn't work and I have to make a work around by redevelopping a quick and dirty feature.

We are generating csv file and I had something like that with legacy code :

```
foo; bar;"foo bar";foobar
"bla ble"; bli;blo;"blu bly"
```

Each field in my csv containing a space must be surrounded by a double quote "

Currently, with my quick and dirty script, my csv file got only

```
foo; bar;foo bar;foobar
bla ble; bli;blo;blu bly
```

This is not good because clients will have a breaking change with my quick and dirty script :D

I am developping a script using shell /bin/bash, I've search arround sed or awk but wasn't able to find something to help me.

Will you ? :)
Thanks !

Comment: Hi! What did you try? Not clear to me what do you want.

Comment: What about fields with leading blanks? Why aren't those quoted?

Comment: Proper CSV parsers and generators exist for many languages. Shell isn't one of them.

Comment: Strictly, you only need to quote if the field value contains quotes or semicolons or newlines.

Comment: @Adrien Bourgouin Sasa, Please add some lines of expexted output

Comment: The CSV format does not require using quotes in this case. Quotes would be needed, if the field contains either the CSV field separator (which in your case seems to be a semicolon), or a _newline_ character. While @chepner is right that a CSV generator would be the best solution for the general case, I don't know of a generator which would create the unnecessary quotes you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i ~ / /) $i = "\042" $i "\042"}1' file.csv
```

Comment: Work like a charm, every "sentence" between ; are in double quote.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr --icsvlite --ocsv --quote-all --fs ";" cat input
```

you will have

```
"foo";"bar";"foo bar";"foobar"
"bla ble";"bli";"blo";"blu bly"
```

I think it's no problem for you to have double quotes for all

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted without reason, but, I just found why this doesn't work for me in 2022. From the manpage "Ignored as of version 6. Types are inferred/retained through the processing flow now.".... so unfortunately this is no longer an option

Comment: Hi @PaulCarroll you are right, it does not work in the latest version. You could use the previous release. And you could ask it as feature here https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/issues

Answer (score 0):

To quote fields that contain spaces (for example `foo;foo bar` -> `foo;"foo bar"`) you can use `sed`:

```sh
sed 's/ *\(\w\+ \)\+\w\+/"&"/g' input.csv > output.csv
```

The pattern `*\(\w\+ \+\)\+\w\+` matches zero or more spaces, followed by a group with a word and one or more spaces `\(\w\+ \+\)`, then one or more occurrences of the group `\+`, followed by a word `\w\+`. The replacement `"&"` quotes the matched pattern.

Comment: Thank, it does the hob I asked but I didn't wanted to share the real csv file example and I failed to told you that I have field like "Mar 17, 2020 09:03:16". In that case, your solution doesn't work. But it perfectly matched what I badly asked netherless, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "foo; bar;foo bar;foobar" | sed s'@;@+@'g | tr '+' '\n' | \
sed s'@^@\"@'g | sed s'@$@\";@'g | tr -d '\n'
```

The first thing this code does, is replace the colon delimiters with a placeholder, that can then be replaced with newlines.

From there, it's simple.  I first replace the start of every new line with double quotes, and then the end with closing double quotes and a colon.

After that, I use tr to remove the newlines again, which puts all of the colon delimited fields back on the same line.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.